# keyStore files being corrupted by git

Tags: java, git, security, keystore

My keyStore files are being corrupted by git. I tried adding .gitattributes and adding below line, it doesn't work.

```
*.keystore binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to .gitignore file, since it contains the sign for your application, does not change and does not need to be tracked.